# How can I parse a json

Tags: json, angular, parsing

alls, 
   I am trying to parse a JSON object in Angular, but it's not working. In my service I created a json object and pasted all data. In component I am trying to parse this json and display all messages in youSend.message.

I want display all messages of youSend in component.html

***jsonDATA***

```
[
{
  "name": "Valentyn",
  "email": "fr@fr.fr",
  "mobile": "0650004641",
  "code_postale": "78000",
  "messages": [
    {
      "youSend": [
          { message: "Hello, how much this PC?"},
          { message: "Ok, I want by"},
          { message: "Thanks for your answers"},
      ],
      "forYouSend": [
        { message: "Hello, this PC 1499"},
        { message: "Ok, I prepare your order"},
        { message: "Thanks for your"},
      ]
    }
  ],
  "orders": [
    {
      "object": "MSI Ge62VR Apache Pro",
      "price": 1499
    },
    {
      "object": "Samsung S9",
      "price": 899
    },        {
      "object": "Qnap-TS251+",
      "price": 499
    }
  ]
}]
```

**file.servive.ts**

```
public users: [] = [{***jsonDATA***}]
public allUsers: [] = [];
constructor() { }
public getUsers() {
   return this.users.map(data => this.allUsers = data);
}
```

**file.component.ts**

```
users: [] = [];
msgUserSend: [] = [];
constructor( private papafils: PapafilsService ) { }
ngOnInit() {
   this.users = this.papafils.getUsers();
   this.msgUserSend = this.users.map(b => {
   return b.messages;
});
```

**file.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   <h4 class="nameColor">{{ user.name }}</h4>
   <div *ngFor="let msg of user.messages">
      {{ msg.youSend.message }}
   </div>
   <div *ngFor="let userOrder of user.orders" class="userOrders">
      {{ userOrder.object }} and {{ userOrder.price }}
   </div>
```

Comment: you should post content instead of image

Comment: what does at meen?

Comment: you should copy the content in your image to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another loop:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <h4 class="nameColor">{{ user.name }}</h4>
    <div *ngFor="let msg of user.messages">
        <div *ngFor="let m of msg.youSend">
            {{ m.message }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let userOrder of user.orders" class="userOrders">
        {{ userOrder.object }} and {{ userOrder.price }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

youSend is an array of messages so you cannot directly use msg.youSend.message

to display array of messages you can try this

```
   <h4 class="nameColor">{{ user.name }}</h4>
   <div *ngFor="let msg of user.messages">
      {{ msg.youSend |json }}
   </div>
   <div *ngFor="let userOrder of user.orders" class="userOrders">
      {{ userOrder.object }} and {{ userOrder.price }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I do like you, I can't display message. I put this code : {{ msg.youSend.message | json }}

Comment: you cannot access msg.youSend.message directly as youSend is an array, I suggested using msg.youSend to display all messages or  you can use a loop to display them one by one

Answer (score 0):

Because messages is an array with 1 item you need use `messages[0]` for accessing `yousend` property.

```
<div *ngFor="let msg of user.messages[0].youSend">
      {{ msg.message }}
   </div>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gm3hwf